# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass while using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, scrape

I am using Nokogiri to scrape data from a HTML document, but I'm running into the following error:

```
`block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage/some"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".Info_listing").each do |x|
  puts x.at_css(".MoreInfo")[:href]
end
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

`at_css` will return `nil` if there's no matching element.

If you want to get `MoreInfo` class element inside `Info_listing`-class element, you'd better to use following code:

```
doc.css(".Info_listing .MoreInfo").each do |x|
  puts x[:href]
end
```

Comment: and also can you tell me how to do it for the next pages? as the site has a pagination thing and i need the data till the last page. And this solution is only for a single page

Comment: @AnshulKalra, The next page's url is: `http://www.indiacom.com/yellow-pages/ambulance-services/bangalore/?page=2`. Change the `page` number, repeat the same thing until there's no more `next` link.

Comment: @AnshulKalra, Or find the `next` button and follow the link, repeat until there's no more `next` link.